# change div content in wordpress home page by a button click

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Hi I am working a website where | have to customise the  Boutique theme completely. All I needed to do now is to have 2 buttons in the home page and when each button is pressed a different set of products has to be displayed in the same page. I am trying using the visibility property but it is not working. Can some one help me with this. All I needed to do is to just change the content of the home page when a button is clicked????

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't here to solve everything. you need to try stuff yourself and show what you did before asking questions which show that you at least tried something.

Comment: Show us your non functional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TABS !!!

[**WordPress Post Tabs**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-post-tabs/) plugin helps you to add various tabs to your WordPress Post or Page easily.

You can add each set of products to a tab. By modifying the styles of tabs, it will looks like a button too!!!

Cheers.